# Ghost outlines in image segmentation

Tags: image-processing

If you observe the results of many image segmentation algorithms, you can notice the occurrence of region borders where a human observer wouldn't draw one, for instance across slow gradient/textured areas. This seems to be a universal phenomenon.

I have annotated the image below with yellow arrows to show what I am thinking about.

My question is twofold: is there a fundamental reason why these occur ? How can we detect such lines ?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this forum is the perfect place, but I found nothing better.

Comment: The fundamental reason they occur is because the segmentation algorithm finds them. Why exactly depends on the algorithm used.

Comment: @adrianN: why do so many algorithms produce ghost outlines ?

Comment: It may be far-fetched, but have you seen seam-carving for photos? If the seam is in the same place, the energy level is low in that curve. The segmentation algorithms loves regions, not half planes (with bumpy edge of course), so these may be artifacts, depressed regions, low-energy seams or artificial borders. Have you seen it in segmentation using region growth?

Comment: @Evil: yep, seam carving is a wonderful technology. My question is about ghost lines in segmentation.

Comment: I know. It is one method of detecting phantom lines and analogy to borders. And these ghost lines are only in total segmentation techniques, not all of them. In the first series you have perfectly good split of the sky, that is later dropped, since the technique "carved" regions with given tolerance. The second one I do not understand. The halo effect appears always when tolerance is higher to cover nasty edges, it always results in "non-obvious by looking" path, but doesn't seem to describe exactly the same phenomenon as first series.

Comment: @Evil How is seam carving "one method of detecting phantom lines" ?

Comment: It is the method of finding minimal gradient (in seam carving it is called energy) in the image, the same principle goes for detecting edges of the components found.